# Why aren't select lists loading values on reset() in react-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, data-binding, react-hook-form

This form works correctly as a regular form - submitting retains the dropdown values. When I use RHF's `reset()` to load data from the URL parameters, The input boxes show the default values but the select fields do not reflect the default values.

The functionality I'm going for here, is to load the values from the URL querystring params, which look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/search?search=dev&location=&environment=On-Site&job_type=Internship&industry=&industry_category=&date_posted=&offset=0&count=25
```

...effectively making it "stateless", so we're able to pass this URL to anyone and it loads the form values, performs the search, etc.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";

import useLookupService from "../../service/lookup_service";

const Search = props => {
    const { onSearch } = props;
    
    const lookupSvc = useLookupService();

    const [searchFormDefaults, setSearchFormDefaults] = useState(null);
    const [locationOptions, setLocationOptions] = useState([]);
    const [jobTypeOptions, setJobTypeOptions] = useState([]);
    const [workEnvironmentOptions, setWorkEnvironmentOptions] = useState([]);
    const [industryOptions, setIndustryOptions] = useState([]);
    const [industryCategoryOptions, setIndustryCategoryOptions] = useState([]);
    
    const { 
        register, 
        setValue, 
        handleSubmit, 
        control, 
        reset,
        formState: { errors } 
    } = useForm({
        defaultValues: searchFormDefaults,
        context: JobSearchForm.type,
        resolver: validator.validateResolver
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!window.location.search) {
            return;
        }
        const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        let defaults = Object.fromEntries(queryParams);
        setSearchFormDefaults(defaults);
        reset(defaults);
    }, [reset]);

    const loadData = async () => {
        let [
            jobTypesData, 
            workEnvironmentsData, 
            industriesData, 
            industryCategoriesData
        ] = await Promise.all([
            lookupSvc.getJobTypes(),
            lookupSvc.getWorkEnvironments(),
            lookupSvc.getIndustries(),
            lookupSvc.getIndustryCategories()
        ]);

        setJobTypeOptions([
            <option key={-1} value="">Please select...</option>,
            jobTypesData.map((x, i) => <option key={i} value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>)
        ]);

        setWorkEnvironmentOptions([
            <option key={-1} value="">Please select...</option>,
            workEnvironmentsData.map((x, i) => <option key={i} value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>)
        ]);

        setIndustryOptions([
            <option key={-1} value="">Please select...</option>,
            industriesData.map((x, i) => <option key={i} value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>)
        ]);

        setIndustryCategoryOptions([
            <option key={-1} value="">Please select...</option>,
            industryCategoriesData.map((x, i) => <option key={i} value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>)
        ]);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    Filters
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a onClick={onClearClick}>
                        Clear Filters
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSearch)} autoComplete="off">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Search</label>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" {...register("search")} />
                        {errors.search && <span className="validation">{errors.search}</span>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Location</label>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" {...register("location")} onChange={onLocationChange} />
                        {errors.location && <span className="validation">{errors.location}</span>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Work Environment</label>
                        </div>
                        <select {...register("environment")}>
                            {workEnvironmentOptions}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Date Posted</label>
                        </div>
                        <Controller
                            control={control}
                            name="date_posted"
                            render={({ field }) => (
                                <InputMask {...field} mask="99/99/9999" />
                            )}
                        />
                        {errors.date_posted && <span className="validation">{errors.date_posted}</span>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Job Type</label>
                        </div>
                        <select {...register("job_type")}>
                            {jobTypeOptions}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Job Industry</label>
                        </div>
                        <select {...register("industry")}>
                            {industryOptions}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Industry Category</label>
                        </div>
                        <select {...register("industry_category")}>
                            {industryCategoryOptions}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">
                        Search
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Search;
```

Note that the selected values and display values are set to the same - a string such as "On-Site".

While debugging, the first `useEffect()` is firing and loading the data before the second one, with reset as its param. I thought perhaps the lists were being reloaded and wiping out the selected value, but I don't see evidence of that.

When setting a breakpoint on the `return` line of the component, `searchFormDefaults` contains the expected values, yet they're always set to the default value on the screen (the initial "Please select..." when they're created.)

This is what I see for `searchFormDefaults` on the final render:

```
{
    "search": "dev",
    "location": "",
    "environment": "On-Site",
    "job_type": "Internship",
    "industry": "",
    "industry_category": "",
    "date_posted": "",
    "offset": "0",
    "count": "25"
}
```

I'm fairly new to react-hook-form so I'm sure I've done something goofy, but I'm unable to spot it or find an explanation anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Was just an async issue that a simple flag solved.

```
const [isDataLoaded, setIsDataLoaded] = useState(false);
```

...then in my data loading function:

```
const loadData = async () => {
    let [
        jobTypesData, 
        workEnvironmentsData, 
        industriesData, 
        industryCategoriesData
    ] = await Promise.all([
        lookupSvc.getJobTypes(),
        lookupSvc.getWorkEnvironments(),
        lookupSvc.getIndustries(),
        lookupSvc.getIndustryCategories()
    ]);

    setJobTypeOptions([
        <option key={-1} value="">Please select...</option>,
        jobTypesData.map((x, i) => <option key={i} value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>)
    ]);

    setWorkEnvironmentOptions([
        <option key={-1} value="">Please select...</option>,
        workEnvironmentsData.map((x, i) => <option key={i} value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>)
    ]);

    setIndustryOptions([
        <option key={-1} value="">Please select...</option>,
        industriesData.map((x, i) => <option key={i} value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>)
    ]);

    setIndustryCategoryOptions([
        <option key={-1} value="">Please select...</option>,
        industryCategoriesData.map((x, i) => <option key={i} value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>)
    ]);
    
    setIsDataLoaded(true);
};
```

...and the hook that needs it:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isDataLoaded) {
        return;
    }
    if (!window.location.search) {
        return;
    }
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let defaults = Object.fromEntries(queryParams);
    setSearchFormDefaults(defaults);
    reset(defaults);
}, [reset, isDataLoaded]);
```